# 'Peer Not Authenticated', parse.com SSL certificate expired

Tags: android, maven, parse-platform

I'm currrently struggling with a 'Peer Not Authenticated' issue while gradling on Android Studio. When I try to clean my project, AS tells me that the issue comes from https://maven.parse.com/repo/com/parse/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml

With an internet browser, I see that the SSL certificate of *.parse.com has expired on Thursday 26th... I've already tried to replace the 'https' with 'http' in order to bypass the checking but it doesn't work.

Here is the head of my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.parse'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.parse.com/repo' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.parse.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
```

Comment: Which package are you trying to load from this repo? Parse libraries are also present im Maven central.

Comment: @Robert Here is a part of my build.gradle:  

buildscript {  
    repositories {  
        mavenCentral()  
        maven { url 'https://maven.parse.com/repo' }  
    }  
    dependencies {  
        classpath 'com.parse.tools:gradle:1.+'  
    }  
}  

Should I change something?

Comment: Please do not press important content into a comment. Edit your question instead.

Comment: @Robert Sorry about that, it's done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into this tonight as well. If you take a look at your IntelliJ log you should see an SSL error associated with reaching that url. To workaround this problem, remove the Parse dependency via the Maven URL and add in the JAR manually to your libs folder.

In your project Gradle add the following under 'dependencies' to reference the manually added libs:

```
compile files('libs/Parse-1.9.4.jar')
compile files('libs/ParseCrashReporting-1.9.4.jar')
```

Remove anything that looks like this from both gradle files:

```
maven {
  url 'https://maven.parse.com/repo'
}

classpath 'com.parse.tools:gradle:1.+'

apply plugin: 'com.parse'

parse {
    applicationId "blahblahblahblah"
    masterKey "ohmasterkeyyousonice"
    retries 3
    uploadSymbols true
}
```

Rock and roll hoochie koo...

*Note*: you just need parse gradle plugin if you are using `ParseCrashReporting`, if not needed remove it.

[Github Issue](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/463)

Comment: @ninehundredt There's no `ParseCrashReporting` in 1.13.0 now, I cant find a way to add the parse gradle plugin from the jar, how can I do that?